# ArangoDB graph operations via REST API

Tags: rest, graph, arangodb, aql

Is it possible to use AQL query language via REST API to make graph queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [HTTP Query cursor API](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpAqlQueryCursor/QueryResults.html) is the right API to do this. It allows executing AQL queries via HTTP.

Example (with a non-graph query):

```
curl        \
  -X POST   \
  --dump -  \
  "http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/_api/cursor" \
  --data '{"query":"FOR u IN users RETURN u","count":true}'
```

You can put your AQL query string (using graph functions) into the `query` attribute of the request.
Bind parameters are optional. If used, they can be put into the optional `bindVars` attribute of the request:

```
curl        \
  -X POST   \
  --dump -  \
  "http://localhost:8529/_db/_system/_api/cursor" \
  --data '{"query":"FOR u IN users FILTER u.name == @name RETURN u","bindVars":{"name":"foobar"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Great! But this AQL bellow works fine in the AQL editor, but not it the REST.

curl -X POST --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/database/_api/cursor --data '{query:LET from = (FOR p IN products FILTER p.name == "p1" RETURN p._id) LET to=(FOR p IN products FILTER p.name == "p2" RETURN p._id) INSERT { _from: from[0], _to: to[0], type: "RELATED" } INTO productsedge}'
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 82
{"error":true,"errorMessage":"expecting attribute name","code":400,"errorNum":600}